# Not Able to uncheck the selected rows checkbox after click of button(which moves selected records to other datatable)

Tags: lightning-web-components

Why the checkbox is not getting unchecked after moving of records 'Federated States of Micronesia' And '
Guatemala' as in pic.

[image]

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
    <lightning-button label="Move Down" onclick={moveDown}>
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-input type="search" label="Enter Search Value" onchange={handleclick} value={searchkey}>
    </lightning-input>


    <lightning-datatable class="table1" data={dataTableRecord} columns={columns} key-field="id">

    </lightning-datatable>

    <h1>Table 2</h1>
    <lightning-datatable class="table2" data={dataTable2Record} columns={columns} key-field="id">
    </lightning-datatable>
    <lightning-button label="Move Up" onclick={moveUp}>
    </lightning-button>
  </lightning-card>


</template>
```

Javascript:

```
import { LightningElement ,track,wire,api} from 'lwc';
import   getCountry from '@salesforce/apex/CountriesDataClass.getCountry';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';
const columns = [
    {label : "Name" , fieldName : "Name"}
]

export default class CountrySearchFunctionality extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns; 
    selRows =[];
    @track data =[]; 
    @track data2 =[];
    @api searchkey ='' ;
 
 

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log("Testing");
        getCountry({searchkey : this.searchkey})
     .then(result =>{
        this.data = result; 
      
        console.log("Result"+JSON.stringify(this.data));
        
     })
      .catch(error =>{
       console.log("Error occured:"+JSON.stringify(error))
      })
      

    }
 
     
    get dataTableRecord(){
      return  this.data.filter((rec) => !this.data2.find((rm) => rm.Id === rec.Id));
    }

    get dataTable2Record(){
      return  this.data2;
    }

    handleclick(event){
     this.searchkey = event.target.value;
     console.log('Search key'+this.searchkey);
     getCountry({searchkey : this.searchkey})
     .then(result =>{
        this.data = result;
        console.log("Result"+JSON.stringify(this.data));
     })
      .catch(error =>{
       console.log("Error occured:"+JSON.stringify(error))
      })
      
    }

    moveUp() {
        let selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(".table2").getSelectedRows();
        console.log("The selected rows"+selectedRows)

        
        if (selectedRows.length >0) {
           this.data2 = this.data2.filter((rec) => !selectedRows.find((rm) => rm.Id === rec.Id));
          console.log('The Sected countries'+JSON.stringify(this.data2))
          
        }
        selectedRows.forEach(e=> console.log('The Selected One'+ e));

      }
      moveDown() {
        let selectedRows = this.template.querySelector(".table1").getSelectedRows();

        console.log('The Selected------'+JSON.stringify(selectedRows)); 
        console.log('Data prsent'+JSON.stringify(this.data));
        if (selectedRows.length >0) {
            console.log();
            
            this.data2 = [...selectedRows];
          console.log('The Sected countries'+JSON.stringify(this.data2))
        
        }
      }
}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class CountriesDataClass {

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<Test_Country__c> getCountry(String searchkey){
    if(searchkey != null && searchkey != '' ) {
        String key = '%'+ searchkey + '%';
        List<Test_Country__c> lstCountry =[Select Id, Name FROM Test_Country__c Where Name Like : key WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        return lstCountry;
    }
    else {
        List<Test_Country__c> lstCountry =[Select Id, Name FROM Test_Country__c WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        if(!lstCountry.isEmpty()) {
            return lstCountry;
        }
        return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to `selected-rows` property of `table1` and set it to `[]` when you're done.

E.g. like so

HTML:

```
<lightning-datatable class="table1" data={dataTableRecord} columns={columns} key-field="id" selected-rows={table1Selected}>
    </lightning-datatable>
```

JS:

```
@track table1Selected = [];


moveDown() {
   /// your code...
   this.table1Selected = [];
}
```

See documentation on Selected Rows property here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification